# 360 degree scrolling with Apple Magic Mouse in Linux?

Tags: kernel, drivers, mouse

I read that there is out of the box support for the Apple Magic Mouse in recent Linux kernels, but does that include full functionality such as multiple mouse buttons and multitouch??

For me the two important things are middle button and 360 degree scrolling (or at least vertical and horizontal scrolling).

Can anyone confirm?? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found this article which seems to confirm what you're asking. Looks to be fully supported as part of Linux Kernel 2.6.35.

- http://digitizor.com/2010/08/02/ubuntu-10-10-supports-magic-mouse-out-of-the-box/

There is also this Ubuntu page titled: [AppleMagicMouse](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch/AppleMagicMouse), for getting it working under Ubuntu. Also the wikipedia page: [Magic_Mouse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_Mouse), also states that it should be fully supported.